# How to generate integers within a range from random bits

Tags: php, random

I have a source of random bits that I would like to massage into integers of various sizes, roughly correlating with the size of popular dice (1-4, 1-6, etc.)

The code I am writing is PHP, so a response in that language is ideal.  However, an algorithmic generic response would be totally fine as well.

I would prefer an answer more sophisticated than simply seeding PHP's random() function with chunks of my random data.

Comment: Do you have an indefinite number of random bits at your disposal?

Comment: And why is using your random data as a seed not acceptable?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that starting with something (even in psuedocode), and then asking if it is valid or not, would probably be a more effective approach. :)

Comment: @Oli, in order: Yes, I have for most intents and purposes an unlimited amount of randomness.  Enough to last forever.  Second, because I am given to understand that seeding the PHP RNG will yield a number that is made by mashing my high-quality randomness up with crappy randomness from the system time and other deterministic factors.

Comment: If your initial seed is truly random, then the resulting sequence from the RNG will be truly random.  (Basically, if `y = f(x)`   and `x` is random, then `y` must also be random.)  However, that's not to say that future values cannot be predicted from past values...

Comment: If you want random numbers and do not want to waste bits see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random integer in the range \[0,n\] from a stream of random bits without wasting bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits)

Answer (score 4):

If you have an arbitrary number of bits available, you might choose to use a rejection method, along the lines of Java's [`Random.nextInt(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).  The pseudocode taken from there is:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
     if (n<=0)
         new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

     if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
         return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

     int bits, val;
     do {
         bits = next(31);
         val = bits % n;
     } while(bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
     return val;
 }
```

`next()` is a function that returns a specified number of random bits, concatenated into an `int`.  You could replace this with your random bit source.

Comment: Hm, this could potentially work.  I could even spool the rejected bits onto the back of the randomness "stack" to conserve if need be.

Comment: Will accept your answer if experimentation validates your suggestion.  :)

Comment: Although this seems to be the common algorithm it will not give exactly random numbers. The error increases as n approaches the maximum integer.

Comment: @soid: What do you mean by "exactly random", and why do you believe the error will increase?

Comment: If I understand this correctly the % (modulo) operator will give the remainder after dividing bits by n. Since bits is not exactly divisible by n, at least for some values of n, there is more chance of generating some values than others because there is a part at the top where bits cannot generate a complete range of n. This error is very small when the number of times n can divide into bits is large. So for small values of n you would not notice it. I am not sure I have explained that very well.

Comment: @soid: This is why it's in a while loop that performs rejection.  This ensures a uniform distribution.

Comment: Ah, got it now, you are right. They take the part off the bottom rather than the top of the range that bits can have. Thanks.

Comment: I agree it is true random, but I still do not understand the algorithm. What happens at the top end of n? Does it retry a ridiculous number of times in the loop when it is near the top?

Comment: @soid: The worst case is n=2^30+1, which gives a rejection ratio of 0.5.