# Generate integer random number using available binaryrandom (which return 0 or 1) function

Tags: c, algorithm, random

In a recent interview, I came through the below question

> Given a function BinaryRandom() which returns 0 or 1 randomly, create
> a function int MyRandom(int) which creates a random number less or
> equal to the given input using BinaryRandom().

As I am a daily stack overflow and GeeksForGeeks user and I recall a similar kind of problem on GeeksForGeeks, see below link

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-random-0-6-generator-using-the-given-random-0-1-generator/

The only difference is on the GeeksForGeeks range was 0-6 and in my case range is <=N (N is input integer number).

and the above solution is derived from SO using the following link

[Creating a random number generator from a coin toss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209162/creating-a-random-number-generator-from-a-coin-toss).

As I beginner in Algorithm, I find it hard to understand above. Can anyone please suggest a simple solution to the above question? or give a simple understanding of it?

Comment: You need to state a lower limit. For example, if N is 3, there are infinitely many integers less than N: 2, 1, 0, −1, −2, −3,… Likely your lower limit is 0 or 1 (inclusive), but we cannot know which until you state it.

Comment: "I find it hard to understand" is not a very precise statement. Can you try to find a more precise statement? Is there some place in the answer to the SO where you read a sentence and couldn't quite grasp it? Can you turn that into a concrete question which you can ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Given a function BinaryRandom() which returns 0 or 1
> create a function int `MyRandom(int)` which creates a random number less or equal to the given input

```
int MyRandom(int max);
```

1. Find bit-width of `max` --> `bitwidth`.  Maybe count right shifts until 0.  E.g. with `max == 42`, we need 6 bits.
2. Form random number by calling  `BinaryRandom()`. E.g. with 6 bits, that will form a number `[0...63]`.

   ```
   int r = 0;
   // Double the value each iteration and add new bit.
   for (i = 0; i<bitwidth; i++) r = 2*r + BinaryRandom();
   ```
3. Insure not out of range: If `r > max`, repeat step 2.
4. Return `r`.

There are ways (not shown) to reduce the chance of having to redo step 2, yet we want to avoid biasing the results by doing something like `r_from_more_than_6_iterations%42`.

Answer (score 2):

Building on chux' answer here is a simple implementation:

```c
int MyRandom(int max) {
    for (;;) {
        int r = 0;
        for (m = max; m > 0; m >>= 1) {
            r += r + BinaryRandom();
        }
        if (r <= max || max < 0)
            return r;
    }
}
```