# Extracting base K random “bits” from a pre-filled random buffer

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, random, cryptography

Say I need N cryptographically-secure pseudorandom integers within the range [0, K). The most obvious way of achieving this would be N calls to [`arc4random_uniform(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arc4random_uniform&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports), and this is exactly what I’m doing.

However, the profiler tells me that numerous calls to `arc4random_uniform(3)` are taking 2/3 of the whole execution time, and I really need to make my code faster. This is why I‘m planning to generate some random bytes in advance (probably with `arc4random_buf(3)`) and subsequently extract from it bit by bit.

For K = 2, I can simply mask the desired bit out, but when K is not a power of 2, things are getting hairy. Surely I can use a bunch of `%=` and `/=`, but then I would have modulo bias. Another problem is when N grows too large, I can no longer interpret the whole buffer as an integer and perform arithmetic operations on it.

In case it’s relevant, K would be less than 20, whereas N can be really large, like millions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random integer in the range \[0,n\] from a stream of random bits without wasting bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the modulus operator and division, you just need to do a bit of extra preprocessing. Generate your array of values as normal. Take `P` to be the largest power of `K` less than or equal to `2^32` (where `^` denotes exponentiation), and iterate over your array making sure all random values are strictly less then `P`. Any which aren't, replace with a new random number which is less than `P`. This will remove the bias.

Now to handle large `N`, you'll need to two loops. The first loop iterates over the elements in the array, the second extracts multiple random numbers from each element. If `P = k ^ e`, then you can extract `e` random numbers from `[0, k)` from each element in the array. Each time you extract a random number from an element, do a floored division by `k` on that element.

Of course, this doesn't necessarily need to be actual loops. You can store two variables (array index, sub-element index) and extract from the `array_index` element as a function gets called. If `sub_element_index == e`, then reset it to zero and increase the `array_index`. Extract a random number from this array element and return it instead.