# Shrink a random range from 0–2 to 0–1

Tags: algorithm, random

A random generator produces values from the list: 0, 1, 2 (with equal probabilty for all three values).

How to get a random number, 0 or 1, with equal probability, from no more than ten uses of the generator.

Comment: Let your generator draw from an array/list of numbers instead. Then put 1x0, 1x1 and 2x2 in it. So you will draw numbers from `[0, 1, 2, 2]`. This gives you `0: 25%, 1: 25%, 2: 50%`. If I got you right, thats what you want, no?

Comment: I can interpret that question in many ways, but you seem to get an average of (0+1+2)/3=1 so divide sum of ten numbers with 20 and round to nearest whole number giving a value of zero or one.

Comment: If you guarantee 50% of each, then the output is not random.

Comment: @stark  Having equal probability of 0.5 does not guarantee 50% each. Even if 50% each were the goal that would change the problem from independent sampling to conditional probabilities, which are still random.

Comment: Roll the dice. If 2, roll again. There is a small change you roll 2 10x in a row. Not sure if that is acceptable.

Comment: @pjs Original question has been changed.

Comment: @stark The changes to the question don't alter that your comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your goal is ultimately to roll a 2-sided die given only a 3-sided die, using a fixed number of rolls of the 3-sided die.

However, this is impossible no matter how many rolls you do, since 2 does not divide 3 (and both are prime numbers). The best you can do here is keep rejecting 2's (and the probability of getting *n* 2's in a row is 1/3^*n*, a probability that shrinks rapidly with increasing *n*).

More generally, it's impossible to roll a *k*-sided die using a *p*-sided die using a fixed number of rolls of the *p*-sided die unless "every prime number dividing *k* also divides *p*" (see Lemma 3 in "[Simulating a dice with a dice](https://perso.math.u-pem.fr/kloeckner.benoit/papiers/DiceSimulation.pdf)" by B. Kloeckner.

See also the following questions:

- [Expand a random range from 1–5 to 1–7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137783/expand-a-random-range-from-1-5-to-1-7)
- [Frugal conversion of uniformly distributed random numbers from one range to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596813/frugal-conversion-of-uniformly-distributed-random-numbers-from-one-range-to-anot)
- [Best way to generate U(1,5) from U(1,3)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770251/best-way-to-generate-u1-5-from-u1-3)

Answer (score -2):

With the edit, in order to shrink the range, you can do a few things

- discard rolls of 2
- if you are certain to roll an even number of times, choose 2 to be 0 or 1 before every other roll
  `(1/3) * .5 + (2/3) * .5`