# How to simulate 60% probability in Java with Math.random()

Tags: java, math, random

I want to do something if there's a 60% chance (only by using Math.random()). For example, a situation where every value in an array has a 60% chance to be set to 1, otherwise 0.

My confusion is whether we should check

```
if (Math.random() < 0.6) { ... }
```

or

```
if (Math.random() <= 0.6) { ... }
```

My thought is that it should be the first because 0.0 counts as a possible returned value, but I would like to confirm which one I should use and why.

Comment: You want `<` but the difference is so small that you're unlikely to ever notice it.

Comment: `new Random().nextInt(100) < 60` maybe enlightens the case: 60 - 40 values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `<` operator.

While this is a simplification, consider that [computers store fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) by adding terms of the form 2<sup>−n</sup>. Most real numbers can't be represented exactly, and literals like `0.6` are converted to the *nearest* `double` value from a finite set.

Likewise, the [`random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) function can't generate real values from a continuous range between zero and one. Instead, it chooses an integer from *N* elements in the range 0 to *N* − 1, then divides it by *N* to yield a (rational) result in the range [0, 1). If you want to satisfy a condition with a probability of *P,* it should be true for *P* ⋅ *N* elements from the set of *N* possibilties.

Since zero is counted as one of the elements, the maximum result value that should be *included* is ( *P* ⋅ *N* − 1 ) / *N*. Or, in other words, we should *exclude*  *P* ⋅ *N* / *N*, i.e., *P.*

That exclusion of *P* is what leads to the use of `<`.

It might be easier to reason about when you consider how you'd use a method like [`nextInt()`,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-) There, the effect of zero on a small range is more obvious, and your expression would clearly use the `<` operator: `current().nextInt(5) < 3`. That wouldn't change if you divide the result: `current().nextInt(5) / 5.0 < 0.6`. The difference between `nextInt(5) / 5.0` and `random()` is only that the latter has many more, much smaller steps between 0 and 1.

I apologize for misleading people with my original answer, and thank [the user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986) who straightened me out.

Comment: There is also a "roundabout" way involving `Math.random`: Use the Fast Dice Roller with a bit generator of the form `Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0` to generate an integer in [0, 100), then check whether that integer is less than 60.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits/62920514#62920514

Answer (score 4):

Use `<`. If you ever want to set your odds to 0%, then you might change your comparison value to 0. Since `Math.random()` can return 0, using `<=` would not result in a 0% chance. As others have noted, the chance of `Math.random()` generating the exact number you are testing against is extremely low, so for all values other than 0 you will never notice a difference.

Comment: What if a chance is `100%`? The `<` would fail for that

Comment: No it wouldn't. `Math.random()` cannot return 1.