# Why do we use Math.floor() for creating random numbers vs. Math.round() or Math.ceil()

Tags: javascript, random

So I am confused why we use `Math.floor()` for creating random numbers versus `Math.round()` or `Math.ceil()`.

For example:

```
var enemyNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
```

Why don't we use `var enemyNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);` or `var enemyNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);`

Comment: This is likely to be opinion-based, considering the fact that they are used differently for different purposes.

Comment: Note: The following shows an alternative way to produce random integers in JavaScript: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046918/how-to-generate-a-random-integer-in-the-range-0-n-from-a-stream-of-random-bits/62920514#62920514

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1527820/1358308 for more explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers from `Math.random()` are in the range 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive). That means you *might* get a 0, but you'll never get 1.

Thus that formula starts off with multiplying by an integer, which in your example will give a value from 0 (inclusive) up to 4 (exclusive).  If you want random integers like 0, 1, 2, and 3, you have to use `.floor()` to get rid of any fractional part entirely. In other words, you might get 3.999, and you *don't* want a 4, so `.floor()` throws away the .999 and you're left with 3.

Now this presumes that what you want is what most people want, a random integer between a minimum value and a maximum value. Once you understand what `Math.random()` returns, you're free to generate integers however you want.

Comment: So, if I wanted the outputs to be 1, 2, 3 or 4, do I use `Math.ceil()`, `Math.round()`, or `Math.floor()`

Comment: Yes, with your formula, using `Math.ceil()` would give you 1, 2, 3, or 4, while `Math.floor()` gives you 0, 1, 2, or 3.  Using `Math.round()` would give you 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4, however I would be wary of that without consulting a statistician because it's a little biased towards 0. Not much at all, but a little. If I wanted that range, I'd use `.floor()` and set the upper bound at 5.

Comment: @Pointy Rounding would give half as much probability for the two end-values of the range than for all of the other integers, unless you extended the range by 1/2 on each side. Easier to just use floor.

Comment: @pjs yea what I really meant was that I am not equipped to analyze that, and using the traditional `.floor()` would work without making my head hurt.

Comment: with `ceil` there's a **very** small probability of getting 0 (2**-53 with common implementations)